# Apply an attribute to an entire class

Tags: javascript, html, inline-styles

Here's my latest argument with JavaScript. I'm trying to apply `display: none` to everything of an entire class through Javascript, but my Javascript keeps failing out at setAttribute, getAttribute, and removeAttribute. No matter how many examples I see online, I just can't get this to work.

My content contains a series of spoilers, rated from 1 to 99. The user can select the minimum "rating" of spoilers to hide (for instance, anything rated 10 and up, 20 and up, 24 and up, 96 and up, whatever).

My function is called from a dropdown called readingspoilers, so that whatever is selected in readingspoilers gets passed to the JavaScript function via an onChange event. So whatever value is selected in the dropdown gets passed to my function as maxNumber.

My JavaScript code is this:

```
function hideSpoilers(maxNumber) {
    var hideUntil = document.getElementById('readingspoilers');
    var spoilerClass;
    for(var elementCounter = 0; elementCounter < maxNumber; elementCounter++) {
//This for loop makes sure that the function goes from 0 to the max and either shows or hides each element of hidespoilers## (from 0 to maxNumber)
            spoilerClass = getElementsByClassName('hidespoilers' + elementCounter);
            if(elementCounter > hideUntil.value) {
                element.setAttribute('display', 'none');   //the function fails here
            } else {
               element.removeAttribute('display');        //the function also fails here
            }
        }
    }
```

Essentially the function does a good job of doing nothing.

The function gets properly called, and the maxNumber value is passed properly. Through a series of window.alert calls, I can tell that it's the setAttribute and removeAttribute calls that are failing. How is it that turning on or off a simple display setting is killing my JavaScript? Can anyone point out what's going wrong?

Comment: Elements do not have a `display` attribute. The display property is part of the `style` attribute.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen From a DOM perspective `display` is a **property** of the read only `style` **object** (not attribute). The `style` **attribute** is the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`display:none` is not an attribute, it's CSS, so you wouldn't use any of the DOM attribute methods with it. Instead, you'd simply set up another CSS class and add that class wherever it's needed with `.classList.add()`. You can also use `.classList.remove()` and `.classList.toggle()`. Super easy.

Here's an example:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Find and loop over all the classes that need to be affected
  document.querySelectorAll(".something").forEach(function(element){
    element.classList.add("hidden");  // Add the class that you want to add
  });
});
```

```css
.something { color:red; }
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<button>Hide the somethings</button>
<div class="something">something</div>
<div class="somethingElse">Something Else</div>
<div class="something">something</div>
<div class="somethingElse">Something Else</div>
<div class="something">something</div>
<div class="somethingElse">Something Else</div>
<div class="something">something</div>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused here now. I just want to make everything with the class hidespoilers10 (or whatever value) disappear. I don't want to apply this to each element individually, since that could get cumbersome and long.

I'm seeing now that I'm trying to get a class through an element. Is there a function that gets the entire class, something like `getClassById` or some such? Or am I barking up the wrong tree? I hope this is easier than having to apply the display to each individual element of 99 different classes.

Comment: @SteveG. You will need to apply the class to each element that needs it - there's no getting around that, but I think you are not understanding that `.querySelectorAll()` makes this very simple and easy to maintain. It won't get cumbersome. And, it doesn't matter how many elements you have, looping over the collection returned from `.querySelectorAll()` means that you'll hit them all, no matter how many there are. Whether you have 5 or 500 items, the code is the same.

Comment: @SteveG. As a follow up, do you see that even though there are 4 elements being hidden in my example, the code that does it is only 3 lines of code? If there were 500 items, the solution would still be just these 3 lines of code.

Answer (score -1):

To set CSS with Javascript, you need to set the `.style` of that element:

```
if(elementCounter > hideUntil.value) {
  element.style.display = "none";
} else {
  element.style.display = null;
}
```

Comment: Inline styles should be avoided. Use CSS classes and the classList API. Also, `display:null` is not valid.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Why should inline styles be avoided?

Comment: Inline styles have the highest specificity and therefore can only be overridden by other inline styles. Inline styles must be applied individually to each and every element they are needed on, causing duplication of code and causing apps to not scale well. Inline styles don't lend themselves to separation of concerns.